# WordPress : get_header() not working in page template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, custom-post-type

I am using page template to fetch data from a custom post type. page name is `client` and  template name is  `client-template.php` inside page-templates folder.

this is code in `client-template .`

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Client Template
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
?> 
<?php get_header();?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content"> 
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
            <?php
                                $args=array('post_type' => 'clients');
                                $query= new WP_Query($args);                               
                // Start the Loop.
                while ($query-> have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

                                        echo the_title();
                                        echo the_post_thumbnail();


                endwhile;
            ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- #main-content -->
```

Now, this is fetching data and shows it. but, header is not getting included whats wrong here , I used types plugin to create  post type and then  selected above mentioned template for client page.
Please help me with this.

Comment: You have a *header.php* page template in your theme root?

Comment: yes i have it . actually two files actually 2 files header.php and header-sitename.php